# Ng-controller ng-model not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie in angular JS.
I have already follow the instructions.

First I'm using ng-init directive to search data. I still using static data for this case. Before I jump into combining it with laravel. I need to know the basic function in angular.

Everything run smooth. But when i change it into ng-controller, and access static data from scope, all i got is error.

This is my source code :

html :

```
<div ng-controller="DataPeople">
    <input type='text' ng-model="search" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname | filter:search">
      name : {{ lon.name }} |  city : {{ lon.city }}
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

javascript :

```
function DataPeople($scope) {
    $scope.listofname = [
                            {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
                            {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
                            {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
                            ];

}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=DataPeople&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

ohya this up on my fiddle too. http://jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/3/

Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Global functions are not controllers anymore, for a loooong time. Use the official documentation, or at least find a more recent tutorial. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: @JBNizet and if OP wants to use an older version, I assume you should shoot him?

Comment: @Shomz What makes you think he wants an old version. You seem to be stuck at 1.2.23, which came out 1.5 years ago. The OP uses 1.5.0, which came out 25 days ago.

Comment: Can you read the damn code?

Comment: Can you read the damn error message? I doubt the OP create his application on jsfiddle. He uses 1.5.0, as the error message shows. He most probably tried to reproduce the error on JSFiddle to share the code with us. But JSFiddle sucks hard, and still uses 1.2.23 by default. Don't blame me for that. Instead, fix your damn answer, and I'll remove my downvote. And stop insulting people

Comment: okay guys, @JBNizet, thanks for correcting us, i didn't account his error.  check out the edited answer.

Comment: Nice to know that all the rage came from you *doubting* that OP wrote that fiddle. Puts a whole new perspective on things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you need to define an ng-app.

```
<div ng-app="your-app-name" ng-controller="DataPeople">
```

Additionally you need to register your Controller with the app.

```
var myApp = angular.module('your-app-name',[]);

myApp.controller('DataPeople', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.listofname = [
       {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
       {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
       {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
       {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
       {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
   ];
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AngularJS 1.4 and newer, your code should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="DataPeople">
        <input type='text' ng-model="search">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname | filter:search">
                name : {{ lon.name }} | city : {{ lon.city }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller('DataPeople', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.listofname = [{
            name: 'guta',
            city: 'tangerang selatan'
        }, {
            name: 'john',
            city: 'jakarta utara'
        }, {
            name: 'oki',
            city: 'singapura'
        }, {
            name: 'billy',
            city: 'singapura'
        }, {
            name: 'george',
            city: 'bandung'
        }];
    }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

About migrate, register your controllers with modules you can read here
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3

The code presented in your question is for obsolete version AngularJS 1.2

Answer (score 2):

HTML file:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DataPeople">
  <input type='text' ng-model="search" >
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname | filter:search">
      name : {{ lon.name }} |  city : {{ lon.city }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

.js File:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('DataPeople', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.listofname = [
          {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
          {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
          {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
          {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
          {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
        ];
    }])
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tr4poanc/)

Answer (score 1):

Your error log shows that you are using `angular 1.5` and in `angular 1.5`, you don't declare global functions as controllers. Try the following **Edited** version

**PLUNKER:**http://plnkr.co/edit/Nhmg9FYJlHy9IwVsIJ0x?p=preview

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World</title>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="DataPeople">
    <input type='text' ng-model="search" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname| filter:search">
      name : {{ lon.name }} |  city : {{ lon.city }}
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('DataPeople', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.listofname = [
                            {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
                            {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
                            {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
                            ];
}]);
})(window.angular);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1.2.23 is completely obsolete. That code won't work with a recent version of angular.

Comment: for the sake of his answer and confusion it does work, i appreciate your helping downvote when people try to help :)

Comment: No, it doesn't. As the error message clearly shows, he's using 1.5.0. So your answer won't help.

Comment: didn't account for that log. Thanks for the correction. i will probably edit it.

Comment: @JBNizet so you're downvoting everybody who made the OP's code work because of the poorly written question? Well done, all rep well deserved.

Comment: No, I'm downvoting answers which use code that use an obsolete version of angular and suggest code that isn't working in the recent version of angular used by the OP, as the error message in the question clearly shows: code is incorrect, recommending an old version is bad. FYI, I **lose** reputation when I downvote. And I usually cancel my downvote when the answer is fixed. The question has no problem at all, BTW. But you must read it correctly to answer, as for every question.

Comment: No, you're just being an asshole - 99% percent of that question deals with the issue, doesn't mention the version used, there's even the fiddle op is using. But you saw the log file... didn't it occur that maybe it's possible for OP to have included a version he didn't want?

Comment: @Shomz You and I just have different standards. You're horrified by the idea of losing 2 rep points. You find it OK to recommend using an obsolete version of a library. You find it OK to recommend code that wouldn't work with a recent version of that library, that the OP uses. On the other hand, I don't care about losing 1 rep point by downvoting you. I explain why your answer is bad according to my standards. I tell you that you would get back your 2 beloved points if you fixed your answer, and you just have a knee-jerk reaction and call me an asshole. And your answer still isn't fixed

Comment: I don't care about the rep, but was shocked by the behaviour of a high-rep member. You should set standards for others, not behave like that. As I said, I took OP's code and made it work. I don't care what version he plans to use, neither should you or we'll end up having those "use jquery" answers. My answer works, no fixing needed unless I hear from OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `ng-app`: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lh1y36m/

```js
function DataPeople($scope) {
    $scope.listofname = [
      {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
      {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
      {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
      {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
      {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DataPeople">
  <input type='text' ng-model="search">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname | filter:search">
      name : {{ lon.name }} | city : {{ lon.city }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 1.2.23 is completely obsolete. That code won't work with a recent version of angular. And the OP is using 1.5.0.

Comment: The fiddle uses the original OP code and I made it work without caring which version he decided to use... Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
html:

```
<div ng-App="myApp" ng-controller="DataPeople">
    <input type='text' ng-model="search" >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="lon in listofname | filter:search">
      name : {{ lon.name }} |  city : {{ lon.city }}
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('DataPeople', function($scope) {
                            $scope.listofname = [
                            {name:'guta', city:'tangerang selatan'}, 
                            {name:'john', city:'jakarta utara'}, 
                            {name: 'oki', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'billy', city:'singapura'}, 
                            {name: 'george', city:'bandung'}
                            ];
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have case-sensitivity issues: ng-App instead of ng-app, myApp instead of myapp.

Comment: Why don't you fix them?